# php curl_init() not working in contact form with recaptcha

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I put contact form in one website in last year. It's working fine till 19th April of this year. I didn't change any version. My php details are

1. PHP version: 7.2.7

Now I am facing this error

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: g-recaptcha-response in submit-form.php on line 14
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function json_decode() in submit-form.php on line 26
>
> {main}
>     thrown in submit-form.php on line 19
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in submit-form.php:19

submit-form.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_POST['name'] != null && $_POST['email'] != null && $_POST['subject']) {
    } else {
        $error = "Complete all the fields";
    }
    if (isset($error)) {
        echo $error;
    } else {
        $g_resp = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $secret = "************"; // Secret key provided by google

        $postdata = "secret=".$secret."&response=".$g_resp; // we will post the data to the google

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $server_output = curl_exec($ch); // response from the google
        $out = json_decode($server_output);
        curl_close($ch);

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $to = '******';

        $headers = 'From: '.$name."\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $subject = $subject;
        $body = 'You have a new message from the contact form'."\n\n";

        $body .= 'Name: '.$name."\n";
        $body .= 'Email: '.$email."\n";
        $body .= 'Subject: '.$subject."\n";
        $body .= 'Message: '."\n".$message."\n";

        if ($out->success == 1) {
            if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                die('Mr.'.$name.' Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.');
            } else {
                die('Message Failed. Pl.Try again');
            }
        } else {
            die('Captcha Failed');
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Contact Form Block -->
<div class="col-md-12 form-block contact-form-block">
    <!-- Form Block Container -->
    <div class="form-block-container">
        <form method="post" id="contactform" action="php/submit-form.php">
            <!-- Name -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control contact-name" name="name">
                    <label>Name*</label>
                </div>
        </div><!-- /End Name -->

        <!-- Email Address -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control contact-email" name="email">
                <label>Email address*</label>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /End Email Address -->

        <!-- Subject -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control contact-subject" name="subject">
                <label>Subject*</label>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /End Subject -->

        <!-- Message -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control contact-message" name="message"></textarea>
                <label>Message*</label>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /End Message -->

        <!-- Recaptcha -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="******"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /End Recaptcha -->

        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-gfort wave-effect">SEND MESSAGE</input>
            </div>
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div><!-- /End Submit Button -->



    </form>
</div><!-- /End Form Block Container -->
```

Pl. help me to solve this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It looks like you're missing the curl and json PHP modules. You should try installing them! On CentOS, the modules are `php-curl` and `php-json`.

Comment: @duper51 Thanks for your suggestion. In localhost also facing same issue